# Calculating model-free implied volatility

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, stochastic-volatility

I am trying to come up with model-free implied volatility as in Britten-Jones, M. and Neuberger, A. (2000) *Option Prices, Implied Price Processes, and Stochastic Volatility*, Journal of Finance, 55, pp839-866, but I am not able to replicate their calculations.
Struggling to understand how they implemented the "broad range" of option prices when their formulas only use two option prices.

Perhaps somebody has done it before and may be able to share an example.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear to me what your question is. Which calculation in said paper are you unable to replicate and what do you mean with how they implement broad range when their formulas use only two option prices? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Their abstract says : "This paper characterizes all continuous price processes that are consistent with current option prices. This extends Derman and Kani (1994), Dupire (1994, 1997), and Rubinstein (1994), who only consider processes with deterministic volatility. Our characterization implies a volatility forecast that does not require a specific model, only current option prices. ..." Where to they use only two option prices ? Without you providing considerably more details your question unanswerable.